# pass by reference for mutable object?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I initialize variable `a` and `b`. `a` has id=559599568, `b` has id=559251864.

I then assign `b` to `a` in the function `change()`, expecting `a` points to `b`'s location and `a` has `b`'s value.

However, what I found is `a` indeed points to `b`'s location within the function (as you can see, they all have id=559251864 when print inside the function change), but once the function returns, `a` points back to it's original id which is 559599568.

Why `a` points back to its original memory id once returns? I thought python is passing by reference if it is a mutable object? Please correct me.

```
a = pd.DataFrame(range(3))
b = pd.DataFrame(range(5))
def change(origin,new):
    print id(origin)
    print id(new)
    origin = new
    print id(origin)
    print id(new)
change(a,b)

Out[24]: change(a,b)
559599568
559251864
559251864
559251864
a
Out[25]:
   0
0  0
1  1
2  2
b
Out[26]:
   0
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
id(a)
Out[27]: 559599568L
id(b)
Out[28]: 559251864L
```

Comment: Every variable is, technically, a reference to another object. But the variables themselves are passed by value; you can't change the value of a variable by passing it as an argument to a function. You may want to read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: Python parameter passing is the same with mutable or immutable objects. See [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: Python is **never** call-by-reference, and the mutability of the object is irrelevant to the evaluation strategy. The Python evaluation strategy is call-by-sharing, which is the same strategy as Java (for reference types) and most modern lanuages, e.g. Javascript, Ruby etc. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Python is passing a reference to the object ([call by sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing)). But your assignment `origin = new` is also *assigning* the reference. So this makes `origin` and `new` refer to the same object within the scope of the function, but doesn't change anything outside the function.

Comment: I think it muddies the waters to say that Python is [pass-by-reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing). It is technically call-by-sharing, which is distinct from call-by-reference. Indeed, the characteristic property of call-by-reference is that assignments are seen by the caller. People tend to use "call-by-reference" rather loosely, though...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks, interesting, learned something today. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for fixing that, it's one of my pet peeves :) Again, I think most people would understand "call-by-reference" to mean "passing a reference to the object", but I like to keep terminology straight, and I believe that drift in this regards just makes everything more confusing